# Does Sitecore support Azure Web App for Containers?

Tags: azure, paas

[Windows Server Containers in Web App are now available in public preview](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/announcing-the-public-preview-of-windows-container-support-in-azure-app-service/), and I wonder if Sitecore provides any sort of support to run an environment in containers, specifically to [Web App for Containers](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/videos/web-app-for-containers-overview/).

Does anyone knows?

Comment: I have the same question, did you ever find an answer to the question?

Comment: @WesleyTremayne, unfortunately no. Hopefully someone from Sitecore see the question :)

Comment: I found this architecture diagram on Azure for Sitecore Solution. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/solutions/architecture/digital-marketing-sitecore/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update:** [Since September 2019, Sitecore will provide support with any Sitecore product issues that are not unique to a containerized environment.](https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/161310)

> This means that the Support team might ask you to replicate the issue outside containers, although they will try to avoid this.

Also some important information on this on the [Sitecore docker repo](https://github.com/Sitecore/docker-images):

> **Important Note about this repository:**
>
> This repository was created to help consolidate efforts around Sitecore and Docker. The code and examples found in this repository are created and maintained by the Community, unsupported by Sitecore.